# How to match Redmine users with their Subversion Repository Authz?

Tags: svn, redmine

I have many Subversion repositories and I use svn+ssh tunnel. I use the "Authz" file for Authentication and Access Rights of the users.

In Redmine the users have the same name as their Subversion username, so Redmine can match them. But the access rights don't match. For example users with no access in Authz file can see the project tree in Redmine.

How can I configure my Redmine so that it fetches the SVN rights for each matched user from authz?